# What is this assembly code doing - Writing to process memory

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

**Edit/Upate**

So I think what confuses me is that:

```
LEA ESI, [EBX + 8*EAX + 4]
```

Loads an address, but:

```
LEA ESI, [EBX + 4]
```

Loads the content (value?) and not an address. How is this not dereferencing?

I am also still not sure what

```
mov [eax+1], ecx
```

does?

**Original Question**

I am trying to learn to read assembly, however I am starting to struggle. Sorry if there are typos, I cannot copy from my lab machine. This is from malicious code, so it may not be optimal.

I think I have a flawed understanding somewhere, but I just can't figure this out.

```
var_30 = byte ptr -30h     
lea eax, [ebp+esi+var_30]
```

My understanding is that a load effective address will become whatever address is calculated from [basepointer-30h+esi]. I don't know what esi or edi is.

```
lea ecx, [esi+edi] 
lea ebx, [esi+6]
```

So I believe that ebx is the resultant address of esi + 6 bytes?

```
mov esi, ds:WriteProcessMemory
```

esi points to the WriteProcessMemory API call

```
mov byte ptr [eax], 68h
```

Which I believe puts the instruction PUSH into the address of eax (which is currently [basepointer-30h+esi]

```
mov [eax+1], ecx
```

I believe ecx, which is now the address of [esi+edi], contains the argument to give to the PUSH instruction. Does this mean that eax+1 now points to the contents ecx (whatever was in [esi+edi]]?

```
mov byte ptr [eax+5], 0C3h
```

This I think puts the instruction RET into the address [eax+5].

```
lea eax, [epb+var_30]
```

This essentially moves eax back/forward by whatever esi was, but I am not sure why?

```
push [ebp+lpBaseAddress]; lpBaseAddress
push 0FFFFFFFFh; hProcess (-1 = this process)

call esi
```

What confuses me:

ebx is used as the argument for nSize, but why would the length of the content would be stored at the address [esi+6]? I initially thought that it was +6 because that could be the length of 'PUSH arg RET (eax to eax+5)',  but it is an address and not a short int. Is the short int (nSize) placed at that address by a previous subroutine?

Why is eax (lpBuffer - the content to write) now at [eax-30h]. Did esi allocate space, but start writing content from the end? Something like:

```
ebp+var_30+esi (eax, start of buffer address) : PUSH(eax) : arg(eax+1) RET(eax+5) : ebp+var_30 (new eax, end of buffer address)?
```

I don't think I fully understand what esi or edi are doing, but I don't have the full code to work out what they are.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have an easier time learning assembly language by starting with simpler programs rather than malware. Malware is notoriously hard to understand.

Comment: @nissimabehcera this looks like windows code judging from the `WriteProcessMemory`, `lpBaseAddress`, `hProcess` and the windows tag. Also it's 32 bit. Your claim that _"edi register store the first parameter of function and esi second parameter of function"_ applies to 64 bit sysv calling convention, not 32 bit windows.

Comment: lea ebx, [esi+6] load effective address of CONTENT pointed by esi+6 . For exemple, if esi register's value is 0xffff1234, [esi+6] is value stored at address 0xffff1234 plus 6 bytes. It's similar of pointers in C language, like (*ptr+6) => *ptr access to value pointed by ptr and add 6 . [epb+var_30] = [ebp-30h] ebp (base pointer register) points to beginning of stack, and stack grows downwards. So if you push data on the stack, a pointer needs to be "decreased" by the size of pushed data.

Comment: For exemple, ebp=0xffff3698 , and i need to store on the stack a value 10 then a value 20 => mov [ebp],10 mov [ebp-4] ,20 ( because a stack is 4 bytes aligned ). "but start writing content from the end " ? yes for exemple , you have "abc" to push into stack, if cpu insert at beginning of string, the content of stack looks like cba but from the end , abc

Comment: The full code, including the call to `WriteProcessMemory`, would help to understand what's going on better.

Comment: Thanks. I did start learning by understanding how to spot loops etc (I know basic c++), but unfortunately the course I am taking is malware and the exam is in a few days. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Updated based on your comments to target what I am not sure about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Addressing your edit

If you are confused by `LEA` think of it like this:

- Calculate everything in the source operand.
- Put the result of the calculation (of the source operand) into the destination operand.

> So I think what confuses me is that:
>
> LEA ESI, [EBX + 8*EAX + 4]

Technically the instruction doesn't care if it's an address (moreover in flat memory everything in a register can be an address).

Take the following pre-conditions:

- EBX = 2
- EAX = 1

Then calculate the source:

- `[EBX + 8*EAX + 4]` = 2 + 8 * 1 + 4 = 2 + 8 + 4 = 14

Move the result into `ESI`:

- `LEA ESI, [EBX + 8*EAX + 4]` ; ESI = 14 (EBX = 2; EAX = 1)

> LEA ESI, [EBX + 4]
>   Loads the content (value?) and not an address. How is this not dereferencing?

The same applies here. Let's say `EBX = 2` and you end up with `ESI = 6`.

> I am also still not sure what
>   mov [eax+1], ecx
>   does?

Take the value of `EAX` then add 1; now this value (`eax + 1`) is a pointer at which you'll store the 32-bit (assuming no size override) value in ECX.

Simple example:

- EAX = 0x8000
- ECX = 2

Now, calculate: EAX + 1 = 0x8001

- Take this value as a pointer (or if you wish a memory location)
- Store the value of `ECX` (2; as a 32-bit value) at address 0x8001.

```
     0x8000  0x8001  0x8002  0x8003  0x8004  0x8005
     +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+
...  |  ?? | |  02 | | 00  | |  00 | |  00 | | ??  |   ...
     +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+
```